# Разные пакеты с одинаковыми классами, норма или ошибка в книге?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

В книге [Pemrograman Java dengan Spring 4](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=6020286681) на 247 странце подключены классы для валидации данных:

[image: Pemrograman Java dengan Spring 4 - Feri Djuandi]
Но вот что интиресно, [javax validation](https://github.com/beanvalidation/beanvalidation-api/tree/master/src/main/java/javax/validation/constraints) и [hibernate.validator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/tree/35ba4c157e81ce6a54e8717418d2718d384ed144/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/constraints) один в один, повторяются названия классов, да и цель у них одна.

Но какой пакет будет использовать Java, не будет ли с этим проблем, да и зачем так сделано ?

На сколько я знаю во избежание двусмысленности к обоим классам следует обращаться по их полным именам, *но я еще зеленый в этом и возможно не прав*, но это же книга.

Также примерно такую же картину можно увидеть в [этом мануале](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-with-bean-validation-api), тут додают maven зависимости javax validation и hibernate validator, правда import делают из разных пакетов, но и тут вопрос, зачем использовать два пакета, если можно обойтись одним ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hibernate](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0)) реализует спецификацию [Bean Validation API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_Validation). Пакет `javax.validation` определен спецификацией, пакет `org.hibernate.validator` содержит специфичные для hibernate классы.

Oracle (теперь Eclipse Foundation) выпускает стандарт Java EE (впредь Jakarta EE), в который входит набор спецификаций. В частности  спецификация Bean Validation API, которая определяет автоматическую валидацию бинов. Спецификация определяют как разработчики могут взаимодействовать с реализацией стандарта. Детали реализации (в данном случае как именно осуществляется валидация) не входят в спецификацию.

Реализация стандарта это конкретные библиотеки, которые осуществляют взаимодействие с БД. Эталонная реализация спецификации Bean Validation API — [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/). Разные производители могут предоставлять свои реализации (например, [Apache BVal](https://bval.apache.org/)), предлагая разработчикам дополнительные возможности и/или улучшение производительности.

Т.о. классы из `javax.validation` стандартные и могут быть использованы в разных реализациях. Классы `org.hibernate` специфичны для Hibernate. Например, Hibernate предлагает нестандартную аннотацию [`Range`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/35ba4c157e81ce6a54e8717418d2718d384ed144/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Range.java). В теории если разработчик использует только стандартные классы, код можно будет беспроблемно перенести на другую реализацию.

Хорошим тоном является везде где возможно нужно использовать классы `javax.*`. Классы `org.hibernate` использовать только когда требуется использовать специфичные для Hibernate возможности. Такой подход позволяет улучшить переносимость кода.

> На сколько я знаю во избежание двусмысленности к обоим классам следует обращаться по их полным именам, но я еще зеленый в этом и возможно не прав, но это же книга.

Вы правы, книга использует импорты со звездочкой для экономии места в примерах. По‑хорошему в коде нужно каждый класс импортировать отдельно, тогда будет видно что именно используется и насколько класс зависит от того или иного пакета.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;
```

Comment: То есть,  если взять данный код с книги, но работать с БД с помощью ORM hibernate, он будет использовать  org.hibernate.validator так как они ему родные, другая же ОРМ будет смотреть в сторону javax ?

Comment: @Андрей Hibernate будет понимать и `javax.validation` и `org.hibernate`. Другие провайдеры, реализующие спецификацию будут понимать только `javax.validation`. Вполне возможно использовать библиотеку Hibernate не обращаясь к пакетам `org.hibernate`.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все стало на свои места, правда логики в книге не понять, так как не вижу смысла им использовать два пакета, да и Hibernate отлично работает с аннотациями javax, даже часто замечаю что аннотации javax а работа с БД Hibernate, почему так, не знаю, но сам также делаю, возможно в будущем буду и другие аннотации использовать, но на данный момент мне достаточно javax

Comment: Пожалуйста! Насколько я понял в [`javax.validation.constraints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html) нет аннотации `Range` для этого автор импортировал пакет из Hibernate